# Multiple parameters in List

Tags: java

I want to do something like this

```
List<Integer, String, String>
```

I want to be able to iteratively retrieve either of these three parameters.
How can I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map/3725732#3725732 related

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Generally when I see this it is a design problem (speaking from my own mistakes as well as others :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is a Tuple class:

```
public class Tuple<E, F, G> {
    public E First;
    public F Second;
    public G Third;    
}
```

Then you can iterate over the list of the tuple, and look at each entry in the tuple.

```
List<Tuple<Integer, String, String> listOfTuple;
for (Tuple<Integer, String, String> tpl: listOfTuple){
    // process each tuple
    tpl.First ... etc
}
```

Comment: @yO2gO, you should consider accepting some answer s to your questions so in the future people know which answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Stackoverflow. I accepted an answer this time and will do it henceforth

Comment: Hi @jjnguy How do I use 'listOfTuple.add()' in your above example?
If I'll do - listOfTuple.add(Tuple<someInteger, someString, someString2>);, this will not work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper class which holds these three variables and then store that wrapper-object in the list.

For instance

```
    public class ListWrapperClass {
    private String firstStringValue;
    private String secondStringValue;
    private Integer integerValue;

    public String getFirstStringValue() {
        return firstStringValue;
    }

    public void setFirstStringValue(String firstStringValue) {
        this.firstStringValue = firstStringValue;
    }

    public String getSecondStringValue() {
        return secondStringValue;
    }

    public void setSecondStringValue(String secondStringValue) {
        this.secondStringValue = secondStringValue;
    }

    public Integer getIntegerValue() {
        return integerValue;
    }

    public void setIntegerValue(Integer integerValue) {
        this.integerValue = integerValue;
    }
}
```

and then use `List<ListWrapperClass>`.

Comment: Ideally, of course, this class would have meaningful names for itself and its properties.

Comment: Yes that's true. But that was unfortunately not specified in the question :)

Comment: Why do you have the getters and setters?  It adds way too much unnecessary code.

Comment: @Yrlec: Yes, was pointing that out for the OP's benefit mostly!

Comment: I prefer to use getters and setters to make it easier to add functionality later on. If I let external classes access the fields instead I make it a lot more difficult to add, for instance, validation before a field gets set.

Comment: @jjnguy: It wouldn't surprise me if these 3 values should have been grouped in a class to begin with, in which case it would likely be useful elsewhere and worth it to make it a proper class. If it's just a throwaway only for use with this particular list, then maybe I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @Colin, agreed.  I just figured this to be a throw away class, thus, I designed my implementation to be as light as possible.

Comment: Past experience leads me to say don't do this for real - it becomes a royal pain usually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<Object>` and then cast whatever you retrieve based on the index, but you may just consider creating a class that holds these three things.

Comment: I don't recommended this non generic solution.

Comment: Neither do I! :)  Just presenting other alternatives.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right choice because the 3 values could not all share the same index and so are not related to each other as they should be. Plus, the lack of type safety with `List<Object>` should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a Tuple from a dependency in Maven central repo

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
    <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You then create an object with two or more types like this:

```
Pair<String, Integer> person = new Pair<>("John", 50);
Triplet<Integer, String, String> person1 = new Triplet<>("John", 50, "single")
```

There are 10 types of tuples, each for a corresponding number of items:

```
Unit (one element)
Pair (two elements)
Triplet (three elements)
Quartet (four elements)
Quintet (five elements)
Sextet (six elements)
Septet (seven elements)
Octet (eight elements)
Ennead (nine elements)
Decade (ten elements)
```

And then you can just use it in a list like any other type.