# Posting to array list

Tags: java, swing

i am looking to pass values entered in my Textfields into an array list, although i cannot seem to do this. i am able to view the details which have been entered in the console when using

```
       System.out.println(houses.get(1).getHouseNumber())
```

but this does not post the newly entered values into the arraylist in my code and i can not understand why.

ArrayList and ActionListener code

```
final ArrayList<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();
        houses.add(new House());
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
 {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        House house = new House();
        house.setHouseNumber(houseNumber.getText());
        house.setStreetName(streetName.getText());
        house.setTown(town.getText());
        house.setPostcode(postcode.getText());
        houses.add(house);
            System.out.println(houses.get(1).getHouseNumber());
            System.out.println(houses.get(1).getStreetName());
            System.out.println(houses.get(1).getTown());
            System.out.println(houses.get(1).getPostcode());
       }
   });
```

GUI Code

```
  public void go(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    HouseNumberLabel = new JLabel ("House Number");
    houseNumber = new JTextField ("");
    StreetNameLabel = new JLabel ("Street name");
    streetName = new JTextField ("");
    TownLabel = new JLabel ("Town");
    town = new JTextField ("");
    PostcodeLabel = new JLabel ("Postcode");
    postcode = new JTextField ("");
    BedsLabel = new JLabel ("Number of beds");
    beds = new JTextField ("");
    PriceLabel = new JLabel ("Price (£)");
    price = new JTextField ("");
    TypeLabel = new JLabel ("Building Type");
    type = new JTextField ("");
    button = new JButton("Submit");
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true)
```

House Class code

```
class House {
    private String houseNumber;
private String streetName;
private String town;
private String postcode;

public String getHouseNumber() {
    return houseNumber;
}
public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
    this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
}
```

Comment: you're not getting values from `JtextField` according to your code. `Submit` is of what type?

Comment: @Darren: a suggestion, don't use capital letter as a first letter in variable name. And from where you are getting houseNumber,town,...and all that information?

Comment: @Harry Joy: Thanks i have changed the variable submit to lower case and i have added additional code showing where houseNUmber is coming from

Comment: You may want to make sure that the event related to your listener is actually being triggered. By knowing what is "submit" perhaps we can infer more. But the bug is not obvious here.

Comment: @edalorzo: ow would i go about making sure the action listener is triggering? and submit is just my jbutton which is supposed to post the details into the arraylist

Comment: @Darren: check for arayList size after every time you add new item in it. In simple word debug your program using some IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: arraysize is 1 and does not increase when details should be submitted, hmm

Comment: @Darren: is your `houses` variable global?

Comment: houses is a global variable yes

Comment: i'm suspecting some other button is getting the event from the form being displayed and not the one posted in your code above. posting the complete code which generates the GUI would help.

Comment: is it necessary to have "implements actionListener" declared in the class? when i do this i am told to add abstract methods but there should be no abstract methods because i have all of the aciotnlistener components :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> used it to print out the array and was presented with `[demo2.House@e2eec8, demo2.House@aa9835]`.

`House@e2eec8` and `House@aa9835`refer to the first and second house in the `ArrayList`, respectively. Try something like this instead:

```
System.out.println(houses.get(0).getHouseNumber());
```

Addendum:

> I cannot see the details in the `ArrayList` in my code.

You can override `toString()` in `House`; that way you can just do this:

```
System.out.println(houses.get(0));
```

Addendum:

> This does not post the newly entered values into the `ArrayList`.

```
System.out.println(houses.get(1).getHouseNumber());
```

Right, this always gets the second entry, starting from 0. The following will always get the last one sent to `add()`.

```
System.out.println(houses.get(houses.size() - 1).getHouseNumber());
```

Addendum: You can loop through the `houses` like this.

```
for (House h : houses) {
    System.out.print(h.getHouseNumber());
    System.out.print(h.getStreetName());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unless you put the results there some other way. You might update your question to show your latest code.

Comment: just tried this and it works, house number is printed in the console, just to clarify, does this mean that the details have now been passed into my array? just i cannot see the details in the Arraylist in my code

Comment: I've elaborated above. You can just print `house.get…`, but I think you're right to verify that it was added. You can also check the result returned by `houses.add(house)`.

Comment: Although this does show me the last entered details they still do not appear to be saving to the array list, which is what i need them to do, when i try and print the array list to see all of its contents i am still shown [demo2.House@12d03f9] instead of the actual details. should the details appear in my code under the line; "final ArrayList<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();" as they would if they were entered in manually in code its self?

Comment: The symbol `House@12d03f9` is a reference to the whole `House` instance. You may want to loop through the array to see them all, as shown above. What textbook are you using?

Comment: not using a textbook really its a piece of extra work ive been given from school, been reading Head First Java to get the jist, why do you ask?

Comment: been doing a module on oo at the moment so doing a little extra work because it interests me.

Comment: Then definitely look at overriding `toString()`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064027/sorting-2d-array-of-string-in-java/5064357#5064357).

Comment: i have just looked at your latest edit regarding looping through the houses and the result is null null null, i assume this means that the values aren't being saved into the arraylist? ps thanks for bearing with me

Comment: Not exactly: it means that three `null` references have been added. If you have a debugger, try stepping through the code to see where it's gone awry.

Answer (score 2):

```
String houseNumber;
```

This variable is not needed, get rid of it;

```
JTextField HouseNumber1;
```

This does not follow proper java naming conventions. Variable names do not start with an upper cased character. The variaible name should be:

```
JTextField houseNumber;
```

Now in the ActionListener you get the text from the text field directly:

```
house.setHouseNumber( houseNumber.getText() );
```

Edit:

```
okButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println( "ok" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped although nothing is posting still, is it necessary to have "implements actionListener" declared in the class? when i do this i am told to add abstract methods but there should be no abstract methods because i have all of the aciotnliistener components :S

Comment: Generally you don't implement the ActionListener interface because you might have more than one button in your class that is listener for ActionEvents. A common solution is to use an annonymous inner class for the ActionListener. See the edit.