# Java Comparable, mutliple/different implenetations of compareTo() method

Tags: java, overloading, compareto

I have this class:

```
public class Sample implements Comparable<Sample> {
public String a;
public String b;
public String c;

public int compareTo (Sample sampleToCompare) {
int compResult = this.a.compareTo(sampleToCompare.a);
      return (compResult != 0 ? compResult : 
                   this.b.compareTo(sampleToCompare.b));    
    }
}
```

I want `compareTo()` to behave or sort using different class properties depending if a flag is set.

So, if `flag == 1` I'd like `compareTo()` to using property `c`, otherwise is `flag == 0`, whatever is currently in the method.

In other words, sort the same class in different ways.

I am not sure how to achieve this. Please help.

Also, please let me know if more information is needed from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
public int compareTo(Sample sampleToCompare) {
    if (flag == 1) {
        return this.c.compareTo(sampleToCompare.c);
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
        // current stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

That's not a very object-oriented way to do it, though. Probably you should have two different comparators and a way to select them based on your "flag" value. Something like:

```
class Sample {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}

class ASampleComparator implements Comparator<Sample> {
    public int compare(Sample o1, Sample o2) {
        return o1.a.compareTo(o2.a);
    }
}

class BSampleComparator implements Comparator<Sample> {
    public int compare(Sample o1, Sample o2) {
        return o1.b.compareTo(o2.b);
    }
}

class CSampleComparator implements Comparator<Sample> {
    public int compare(Sample o1, Sample o2) {
        return o1.c.compareTo(o2.c);
    }
}

public Comparator<Sample> pickComparator(int flag) {
    switch (flag) {
        case 0:
            return new ASampleComparator();
        case 1:
            return new BSampleComparator();
        case 2:
            return new CSampleComparator();
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad flag value: " + flag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a comparator example? Knowing that a,b,c are String

Comment: @Sabertooth: Updated answer with a Comparator example

Answer (score 4):

If you want to implement different kind of sorting, you should take a look at [java.util.Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

```
public class SampleComparatorA implement Comparator<Sample> {

    public int compare(Sample a, Sample b) {
        // Your sorting
    }
}
```

And use [java.util.Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method with the Comparator as the secound parameter instead.

```
Collections.sort(aSampleList, new SampleComparatorA());
```

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064027/sorting-2d-array-of-string-in-java/5064357#5064357).

Answer (score 1):

You should make your flag static so the comparison will be consistent (as described in [Effective Java, item 12](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/methods-common-to-all-objects/63)), otherwise, you might get that `a.compareTo(b)` returns that `a > b`, but `b.compareTo(a)` returns that `b > a`. So the simplest implementation I can think about is:

```
public class Sample implements Comparable<Sample> {
public String a;
public String b;
public String c;
public static boolean my_flag = false;

public int compareTo (Sample sampleToCompare) {
    if (flag) {
        return this.c.compareTo(sampleToCompare.c);
    }
    int compResult = this.a.compareTo(sampleToCompare.a);
      return (compResult != 0 ? compResult : 
                   this.b.compareTo(sampleToCompare.b));    
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't buy the `static` part. `final`: yes. `static`: not necessary.

Comment: @Jason - why would you make it final, if it might change? And why not static? I would really like an answer, as I might be missing something.

Comment: #MByD: my bad, I was thinking about `Comparator`, not `Comparable`, where you might want to have different ones. As for `final`, you really don't want to stick objects as keys in a `TreeMap` and change the rules midstream.