# How to store Objects from Database?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, object, performance

I am developing a java application which will be graphically depicting and organizing hundreds of objects. Each of these objects is loaded in from a SQL database, for use in this program.

I plan to keep a local copy of all the data, retrived through a `JDBC` connection, and then sort it locally (Likely with `Merge Sort` as that is my favorite)

**How would you recommend I store the data locally?** Ideally, it would be very easy to traverse, sort and compare to the source Database.

Currently, I have objects called `Ideas`  which are populated from the database. Then, to display them, I create the same number of `IdeaGraphics` objects and add them to the appropriate JPanels. This can be quite slow at times.

Comment: How to store them locally (I assume you mean in memory) depends mostly on how you access them. If it is geometrical/spatial objects that you will access in different regions of some space, then a quadtree may be suitable. If you access objects by some key then a map/dictionary is more suitable etc. etc. If you need scalability in displaying lots of graphical objects, you probably want to draw them yourself onto the panel rather than creating a lot of controls.

Comment: I do want to represent them graphically, but I need to be able to click on each one individually. Would i just have to do the pixel math to figure out which one was clicked?

Comment: Yes, as suggested you will just have a custom panel which draws your objects. When the user clicks you can calculate which object was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and use [`Collections.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), a modified mergesort, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064027/sorting-2d-array-of-string-in-java/5064357#5064357).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you already did that but it's not so clear in your question:

You can get almost as many instances of your data class (Ideas) but it's not the same at all with graphic classes. Limit the number of widgets and graphics to 1.

Build your own custom `JPanel` class, give it a list of Ideas and override the `paintComponent` method to draw all items in the list.

If your visible area is large, double buffer it.

Comment: +1 for a great idea, which will help me eliminate one of my big bottlenecks =]

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with that and not good idea to holding lots of data in local Memory, with idea to simulate, excelent optimalized preprocesor from `Sql Engine` (most of todays engines), then basically faster as best `EndUser PC`

and if you have some *WHATEVER* permisions to the Database, then there are still exist option(s) to loading data from DbEngine to the [Embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) (on Memory), maybe to [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or maybe [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)