# Sorting a 2D Integer array based on a column

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D-array that I want to sort based on the second column. The first column should remain paired with the second column.

The 2D-array is initially as follows (2x10 matrix):

```
0 10
1 9
2 9
3 9
4 15
5 10
6 4
7 8
8 11
9 12
```

I want the above 2D-array to be sorted like this:

```
4 15
9 12
8 11
0 10
5 10
1 9
2 9
3 9
7 8
6 4
```

Now, I've tried adapting the answer from: [Sort a two dimensional array based on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column) into this code:

```
Arrays.sort(theArray, new Comparator<Integer[]>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2)
    {
        Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[1];
        Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[1];
        return numOfKeys1.compareTo(numOfKeys2);
    }
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to sort the array at all. When printing the array after calling the sort() function the array is in its initial order.

I also tried adapting the answer from here: [sorting 2D array of String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064027/sorting-2d-array-of-string-in-java) but I encountered the same problem.

Have I made some fatal mistake when adapting these solutions, or should my code work?

Also, how would I go about sorting this array in descending order? Would I replace the return statement in compare() with this line?

```
return -numOfKeys2.compareTo(numOfKeys1);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Just posting the rest of my code to see if the problem is elsewhere.

```
public void Sort()
{   
    Integer[][] theArray = {{0,10},{1,9},{2,9},{3,9},{4,15},{5,10},{6,4},{7,8},{8,11},{9,12}};;

    dump(theArray);
    Arrays.sort(theArray, new Comparator<Integer[]>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2)
        {
            Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[1];
            Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[1];
            return numOfKeys1.compareTo(numOfKeys2);
        }
    });

    System.out.println("====");
    dump(theArray);     
}

public void dump(Integer[][] array)
{
    for(int p = 0, q = 10; p < q; p++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[p][0] + " " + array[p][1]);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've got it working. Thanks everyone for your help. I had multiple Sort() functions (an older one that wasn't working, and the one you see above), and it turns out I was calling the wrong one, even though I thought I changed the call. Just one of those days.

Feel free to use the code above if you want to sort an array. It's fully working now.

Comment: That code shouldn't run; the array of arrays has a single array with a bunch of two-element arrays in it, you're treating it as a an array of two ten-element arrays when you print it.

Comment: You're right, I was getting my indices mixed up. Thanks for correcting me. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. To reverse order you'd negate the original `compareTo`, *or* swap the variables, but not both.

We'll probably need to see the rest of the code to understand why you're seeing what you're seeing; I cut and pasted your code verbatim, so odds are good the issue lies elsewhere.

---

```
dump(theArray);
Arrays.sort(theArray, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
    public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {
        Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[1];
        Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[1];
        return numOfKeys1.compareTo(numOfKeys2);
    }
});
System.out.println("================");
dump(theArray);


0 10 
0 10 
1 9 
2 9 
3 9 
4 15 
5 10 
6 4 
7 8 
8 11 
9 12 
================
6 4 
7 8 
1 9 
2 9 
3 9 
0 10 
0 10 
5 10 
8 11 
9 12 
4 15
```

Comment: Thanks for testing my sort() function. I'll post the rest of my code now.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can easily do it like below. This will sort array based on 2nd column in descending order.

```
Arrays.sort(theArray, (a, b) -> b[1] - a[1]);
```

Comment: If your Java version is 1.8 and above

Answer (score 1):

Code works for me too. Sorry for the messy code, i had to do a quick test. Regards!

```
import java.util.*;

class arraysort {

    public static Integer[][] mysort(Integer[][] ar) {
        Arrays.sort(ar, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {
                Integer numOfKeys1 = int1[1];
                Integer numOfKeys2 = int2[1];
                return numOfKeys1.compareTo(numOfKeys2);
            }
        });
        return ar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        Integer[][] myarr = {{0, 10}, {1, 9}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}, {4, 15}, {5, 10}, {6, 4}};

        for (Integer[] i : myarr) {
            System.out.println(i[0] + "," + i[1]);
        }

        myarr = mysort(myarr);

        for (Integer[] i : myarr) {
            System.out.println(i[0] + "," + i[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran your code entirely and it worked... one thing though I had to replace the

```
System.out.println(array[0][p] + " " + array[1][p]);
```

with

```
System.out.println(array[p][0] + " " + array[p][1]);
```

to run the code because otherwise it gives an array index out of bounds exception.

Negating the compareTo return is easier than swapping the values and allows easy change.

Comment: Thank you, my indices were mixed up. I've got my program working now.