# How do I order a string array ascending and descending alphabetically? C# .NET or Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, arrays, string

Well, I have a string array:

```
String array[] = new String[5];

array[0]="abc";
array[1]="aab";
array[2]="aaacb   sf";
array[3]="  ab";
array[4]="hello";
```

How do I order ascending and descending?

Comment: Pick a language... there are different approaches for each...

Comment: What does the first result say when you google for "sort java array"?

Comment: For java you can look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702299/sort-string-array  & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), you could do:

```
array = array.OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();
```

to sort ascending

And

```
array = array.OrderByDescending(d => d).ToArray();
```

to sort descending

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample: The "Array.Sort" function does this for you:

```
char[] array = { 'z', 'a', 'b' }; // Input array.
Array.Sort<char>(array); // Sort array.
foreach (var c in array)
    Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Look at [dotnetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort).

The LINQ functions ordering the array ascending and descending is also very well described with an sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDERBY` from LINQ to sort any collection (in .NET).

Comment: OrderBy does not "sort the collection" as such; it creates a new sequence of the sorted data, without changing the collection

Comment: Yeah, thats what i meant. Thx for clarification