# How to sort a Vector of Vectors?

Tags: java, sorting, vector

In Java I am wondering how to sort vectors of vectors on a particular column where one vector is used as a row and one vector is used to hold all the row vectors e.g.

```
 Vector row = new Vector();
    Vector main = new Vector();

    row.add("Column1");
    row.add("Column2");
    row.add("Column3");

    main.add(row);
```

Then sort the variables in one of the columns e.g. `Column2`.

Thank you

Comment: Please search around, this gets asked **a lot**. Also: you're suffering from [object denial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map). Making the inner Vector an object of a custom class will make your life much easier in the long run!

Comment: You should really be using `List<T>` and `ArrayList<T>` in Java now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* write a [`Comparator<Vector>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares two `Vector` objects based on their second element and use [`Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with that.

**But** in the long run you'll be much better off if you get rid of the `Vector`-in-`Vector` construct and replace the inner `Vector` with a custom class that represents the data that you want it to represent. Then you'd write a `Comparator<MyClass>` which would be much easier to interpret ("oh, this comparator compares based on the first name" instead of "why does this comparator take the element at index 1 and compare that? What does that mean?").

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to sort in 'main' rather than 'row':

```
Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
Vector<Vector<String>> main = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Collections.sort(main, new Comparator<Vector<String>>(){
    @Override  public int compare(Vector<String> v1, Vector<String> v2) {
        return v1.get(1).compareTo(v2.get(1)); //If you order by 2nd element in row
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

(why do people still use `Vector` and avoid generics? I should ask that question on SO... ;) )

Let me suggest a modern refactoring first:

```
List<List<String>> main = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
row.add("Column1");
row.add("Column2");
row.add("Column3");
main.add(row);
```

Now we can look at `Collections.sort(Comparator<T> comp)` which will do the sorting of `main`. We just have to implement a Comparator class that is able to compare two rows according to our parameter - which is a certain column, in our case:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<List<String>> {
  private int columnIndex = 0;
  public MyComparator(int columnIndex) {this.columnIndex = columnIndex;}

  @Override
  public int compare(List<String> thisRow, List<String> otherRow) {
    return thisRow.get(columnIndex).compareTo(otherRow.get(columnIndex));
  }
}
```

Use the comparator like this:

```
Collections.sort(main, new MyComparator(1));  // will sort according to "column2"
```

*Note* - this is an incomplete implementation, I don't check if the index values are valid and if all rows have the same size .. should be done in production code.

Comment: People use Vector because they don't know that the Collections classes exist, or they don't understand the Collections classes.  I used the Properties class for a long time.

Comment: You *could* define `MyComparator` like this: `class MyComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparator<List<T>>`. This way you can also use it on `List<Number>` or other lists of `Comparable` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are maybe not the best representation of your table. Have a look at [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a reusable Comparator that can be used to sort on any index in the Vector (or List or Array). The [Column Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/) does this for you.