# Convert ArrayList fetched from HashMap to an Array

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

How can i do this ? 
When i stored my fields in HashMap , i did it like simple Objects

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();

    map.put ("Autorul",numelePrenumeleAutorului);
    map.put ("Denumirea cartii",denumireaCartii);
    map.put ("Culoarea cartii",culoareaCartii);
    map.put ("Genul cartii",gen);
    map.put ("Limba",limba);
    map.put ("Numarul de copii",numarulDeCopii);
    map.put ("Numarul de pagini",numarulDePagini);
    map.put ("Pretul cartii",pretulCartii);

     ArrayList arl=new ArrayList();

     for (int i = 0;i<numarulDeCopii;i++) {

     arl.add(coeficientUzura[i]);
}
     map.put ("Coeficientii de Uzura",arl);
```

I access values from HashMap (look for the last lines)

```
Carte (String caleSpreFisier) {

HashMap map = new HashMap();

File file = new File(caleSpreFisier); 

try  {

FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);  
ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);  
map = (HashMap)s.readObject();         
s.close();

 } catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println("An exception has occured : "+e);     
    }

for (Object key :map.keySet()) {

    if (key.equals("Autorul")) {

        numelePrenumeleAutorului = (String)map.get(key);

    }

      if (key.equals("Denumirea cartii")) {

      denumireaCartii = (String) map.get(key);
    }

    if (key.equals("Culoarea cartii")) {

        culoareaCartii = (String)map.get(key);
    }


    if (key.equals("Genul cartii")) {

        gen = (String) map.get(key);

    }

    if (key.equals("Limba")) {

        limba = (String) map.get(key);

    }

    if (key.equals("Numarul de copii")) {

        numarulDeCopii = (Integer) map.get(key);

    }

    if (key.equals("Numarul de pagini")) {

        numarulDePagini = (Integer) map.get(key);

    }

    if (key.equals("Pretul cartii")) {

         pretulCartii = (Double) map.get(key);
    }

    if (key.equals("Coeficientii de Uzura")) {

        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();


        Object me = map.get(key);

        System.out.println(me);

        //temp = (ArrayList) map.get(key);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object[] array = ((ArrayList) map.get(key)).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of: you're in [object denial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map). Your `HashMap` should really be a proper class that you wrote with the real properties to hold your different fields.

That way you also don't have to do that ugly "name of the property"-to-local-variable mapping.

Next: *if* what you put into the map is an `ArrayList`, then you can just cast what you get out to that type again:

```
ArrayList temp = (ArrayList) map.get(key);
```

Comment: thx, but what about name of properties , this is normal cause a typed names in my native language