# how to sort a vector of hashmaps

Tags: java, sorting, vector, hashmap

i have a Vector of Hashmap and the HashMap contains different data types:

```
Vector<HashMap<String, Object>> theVector= new Vector<HashMap<String, Object>>();
```

theResults contains this HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Object> theHashMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

theHashMap has these data:
(pretend this is a for-loop)

```
//1st set

theHashMap.put("BLDG_ID", 111); //int
theHashMap.put("EMP_NAME", "AAA"); //String
theHashMap.put("FLAG", true); //boolean

theVector.add(theHashMap);

//2nd set

theHashMap.put("BLDG_ID", 222); //int
theHashMap.put("EMP_NAME", "BBB"); //String
theHashMap.put("FLAG", false); //boolean

theVector.add(theHashMap);

//2nd set<br>
theHashMap.put("BLDG_ID", 111); //int
theHashMap.put("EMP_NAME", "CCC"); //String
theHashMap.put("FLAG", false); //boolean

theVector.add(theHashMap);
```

I want to sort the contents of my vector of HashMap according to BLDG_ID so that when I display the data it would look like

```
BLDG_ID || EMP_NAME
111     ||    AAA
111     ||    CCC
222     ||    BBB
```

How do I do that?

Comment: my &gt; and &lt; have been stripped here's the declaration for theVector again''
Vector &lt;HashMapvString, Object&gt;&gt; theVector= new Vector&lt;HashMap&lt;String, Object&gt;&gt;();

Comment: Please learn how to use Markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: argh. my < and > have been stripped here's the declaration for theVector again''

 Vector <HashMap <String, Object>> theVector= new Vector<HashMap<String, Object>>(); 

HashMap<String, Object> theHashMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be much better off doing something like this: Instead of using a hashmap for your values, just make a class. Then you'll get `compile time checking` on your operations, which will help prevent errors down the road.

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    int buildingId;
    String name;
    boolean flag;

    Employee(int b, String n, boolean f) {
        buildingId = b;
        name = n;
        flag = f;
    }

    public int compareTo(Employee other) {
        if(other.buildingId == this.buildingId) 
            return name.compareTo(other.name);
        return buildingId - other.buildingId; // potential for overflow, be careful
    }

}
```

Then you can just sort the vector using whatever sort you want. If you use ArrayList (the modern form of Vector) you can use `Collections.sort(myList);`

```
List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<Employee>();
emps.add(new Employee(111,"AAA",true));
emps.add(new Employee(111,"CCC",false));
emps.add(new Employee(111,"BBB",false));

Collections.sort(emps);
System.out.println("Building Id,Employee Name");
for(Employee emp : emps) System.out.println(emp.getCSV()); // or however you want to format it
```

Comment: +1: Another case of [object denial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map).

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the hashmap because some other process needs that object

Comment: @Joachim that is a gem of a term!

Comment: @ayeenc That should be addressed. If nothing else, I would use it internally for your own sorting purposes. It will simplify things in the long run. But really, you should be talking to your consumer of the hashmap and get them to transition to the object.

Comment: i also cannot change the Vector to List... i would break a lot of other functionalities/dependencies if i change any data type

Comment: I looked and you don't have to change Vector to List. It the only *major* difference between them is that Vector is synchronized and ArrayList isn't. (There are other differences, but that's the key one.) So you can still use `Collections.sort()` with your vector. If you pass in a custom comparator, you can use `sort(theVector,comp)` - the comparator would be equivalent to the `compareTo` method (basically).

Answer (score 1):

Implement a custom `Comparator<Map<String, Object>>`, then call Collections.sort

Note: You might want to use ArrayList instead of Vector.

Comment: hi puce, im not sure i understand what u meant by custom Comparator..would you mind giving an example?

Comment: Have a look at Bhesh Gurung's answer. He gave a sample of such a Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> vector = new Vector<Map<String, Object>>();

Collections.sort(vector, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
        return ((Integer) map1.get("BLDG_ID")).compareTo((Integer) map2.get("BLDG_ID")));
    }            
});
```

**Update:** For your code:

After the "last"

```
theVector.add(theHashMap);
```

add the following

```
Collections.sort(theVector, new Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, Object> o1, HashMap<String, Object> o2) {
            return ((Integer) o1.get("BLDG_ID")).compareTo((Integer) o2.get("BLDG_ID"));
        }            
    });
```

Comment: Use the interface (Map) instead of the implementation (HashMap). Besides I think the second generic parameter should be Object.

Comment: thanks Bhesh Gurung & puce,
pardon my ignorance but how do i use the above code given my data sample?do i add that custom  Comparator inside the same method where i have the  theVector.add(theHashMap); and theHashMap.put("BLDG_ID", 222);//int<br>, etc?

thanks for your patience

Comment: @ayeenc: Yes, after you are done adding all the `HashMap`s into the vector, that's when you need to sort your vector right?

Comment: @ayeenc: Also, since this is your first question here in SO, you can accept the answer if your problem is solved. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.