# calling a hashtable with variable

Tags: java, hashtable

I am using multiple hashtables for a program viz table1 table2 table3 etc. Each table has 3 key-value pairs. the keys are same with different values. 
Now in the UI of my program i have a comobobox to pick the table name from user. Once it is selected i am storing it in a variable and would like to use this variable to open the appropriate table.

Thanks Eric Coolman for [this piece](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/codenameone-discussions&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hl=en&parenturl=http://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/HashTable/codenameone-discussions/c-utanyjEAs/cKMotTk6MKkJ) which i have edited here for my query.

```
Hashtable table1 = new Hashtable();

table1 .put("COL1", Double.toString(dvalue1));
table1 .put("COL2", value2);
table1 .put("COL3", value3);

Hashtable table2 = new Hashtable();

table2 .put("COL1", Double.toString(dvalue4));
table2 .put("COL2", value5);
table2 .put("COL3", value6);

// reading that value back:

double dvalue1 = Double.parseDouble((String)table1.get("COL1"));
double value6= Double.parseDouble((String)table2.get("COL3"));`
```

here how can i use a variable instead of table1 and table2? what is the syntax. I am new to java.

Comment: Do you want to have an array of Hashtables?

Comment: The usual advice to the beginner: **do not use `HashTable`**, it has had a legacy status ever since Java 1.2. Use `HashMap` instead.

Comment: I think my question is still unanswered. If, String var = table1; then how to use 'var' instead of 'table1'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of, your structure looks like you are in [object denial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map): what you've got as `Hashtable` object should probably be objects of a custom type with 3 fields (`col1`, `col2` and `col3`; or more readable versions of that).

Next: you can simply use a third variable to switch on which object you read from:

```
Hashtable readFromMe;
if (someCondition)
  readFromMe=table1;
else
  readFromMe=table2;

Object o = readFromMe.get("COL3");
```

This code would read from `table1` if `someCondition` is `true` and from `table2` otherwise.

Also, a shorter version of the first 5 lines of the code above would be `Hashtable readFromMe = someCondition ? table1 : table2;`.

Comment: Even shorter: `(someCondition? table1 : table2).get("COL3");` :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: yes, it's shorter, but I'd argue that it's a tad less readable and especially for a beginner it might be hard to comprehend (they tend to be used to calling methods on variables and not on arbitrary expressions).

Comment: @ Sauer: Thanks but, I have more than 6 such tables therefore I would like to have a variable address the hashtable name.@ Topolnik: I am using codename one for developing an application which i learn does not yet support hashmaps. hence the use.

Comment: Are all of those tables the same structure? Then you might want an array or another map (`HashMap`).

Comment: It's a common problem among beginners. At first it looks "simpler" to use a map for everything as opposed to creating new classes, but in the long run you'll run into many problems (for example I see you already to a lot of casting that wouldn't be necessary with a custom class). The term "object denial" is a name for this problem that I'm trying to get into common use ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put your both the tables in another hash table and access the table you want using the key.

```
Hashtable<String, Hashtable> tables = new Hashtable<String, Hashtable>();
Hashtable<String, String> table1 = new Hashtable<String, String>();

table1 .put("COL1", Double.toString(dvalue1));
table1 .put("COL2", value2);
table1 .put("COL3", value3);

tables.put("table1", table1);


Hashtable<String, String> table2 = new<String, String> Hashtable();

table2 .put("COL1", Double.toString(dvalue4));
table2 .put("COL2", value5);
table2 .put("COL3", value6);

tables.put("table2", table2);

// reading that value back:

double dvalue1 = Double.parseDouble(tables.get("table1").get("COL1"));
double value6= Double.parseDouble(tables.get("table2").get("COL3"));`
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a query on using nested hashtables which you answered before my asking. but since i have more than 6/7 tables i would like to know if the hashtable name can be called from a variable.

Comment: I did not get this "if the hashtable name can be called from a variable" ?

Comment: I mean using a string variable to call the relevant hashtable. As i said i have a comobobox on my UI where the user selects the table. I can store this selection in a string variable and then use this variable to call the relevant table for getting the key value pairs.

Comment: Yes you should associate each string unique string variable to each table.

Comment: I think my question is still unanswered. If, String var = table1; then how to use 'var' instead of 'table1'. in the above code. –

Comment: You cannot assign String var = table1; which is hashtable. You should name Hashtable variable as table1 and follow the same convention for keys in hashtable i.e, "table1".

Comment: thanks for sticking around. i think i am not putting my question properly. In your code above, while reading the values (last 2 lines) "table1" & "table2" are called which are names of the respective hashtables. Can i use a string variable for this something like this: --same code-- String name = "tables"; String name1 = "table1"; String name2 = "table2";  double dvalue1 = Double.parseDouble(name.get(name1).get("COL1")); so that i still get the same result. hope i am clear.

Comment: But it doesn't in my case, double dvalue1 = Double.parseDouble((String)table1.get("COL1")); (this works) but String name = "table1"; double dvalue1 = Double.parseDouble(name.get("COL1")); this doesn't. There is red line below get saying cannot find symbol method get. I am using netbeans. Is the syntax correct.

Comment: String tablename = "table1";double dvalue1 = Double.parseDouble(tables.get(tablename).get("COL1"));