# Get Key value from iterator

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap, which contains another HashMap. I want to iterate over the first HashMap and use the Key values from that. Then, as I iterate over the first HashMap I want to start an inner loop iterating over the second HashMap, getting all the values.

The problem I have so far is that I can't figure out how to get the keys from the Iterator.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> subitems = myHashMap.get("mainitem1");

Collection c = subitems.values();
Iterator itr = c.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
    // Get key somehow? itr.getKey() ???

    // contains the sub items
    HashMap productitem = (HashMap)itr.next();
}
```

The data that i get from `subitems` is this:

```
{Item1{0=sub1, 1=sub2}, Item2{0=sub3, 1=sub4}}
```

Then, in the while loop `productitem` contains the 'sub items'. But i can't find out where i can get the key value 'Item1' and 'Item2' from.

How can i get those?

Comment: In addition to using `entrySet()` as per the answers below, you can also use `keySet()` to get just the keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't get the key from `values().iterator()`.

You need to use [`entrySet().iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29). That will return [`Map.Entry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects on which you can call [`getKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) and [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29).

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Key> entry : subitems.keySet()) {
  Integer key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();

  // do stuff
}
```

I'd also like to add that having deeply nested maps of lists of maps is usually a sign that you really want to write custom classes to hold your data. **Especially** when the maps have pre-defined keys to be used and interpretation of the values in the lists depends on the position within the list! I call this code smell ["object denial"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3725728/40342).

Answer (score 3):

You can't go from value to key in a map. (There may be several keys mapping to the same value!)

You can iterate over the map entries though using `subitems.`[`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)`.iterator()`, or you can iterate over the keys, and in each iteration retrieve the associated value through `subitems.get(key)`.

Comment: I'd discourage iterating over the keys and calling `get()`, because it will almost certainly have worse performance than iterating over the keyset.

Comment: Ok. I think the code is slightly cleaner though, but that's a matter of taste perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (using iterators):

```
Set<Entry<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>> c = subitems.entrySet();
Iterator<Entry<String, HashMap<Integer, String>>> iterator = c.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Entry<String, HashMap<Integer, String>> entry = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("key:" + entry.getKey());
    HashMap<Integer, String> innerMap = entry.getValue();
    if (innerMap == null) {
        continue;
    }
    Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> innerIterator = innerMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<Integer, String> innerEntry = innerIterator.next();
        System.out.println("key:" + innerEntry.getKey() + " value: " + innerEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

or like this using foreach structure:

```
for (Entry<String, HashMap<Integer,String>> entry : subitems.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println("key:" + entry.getKey());
    HashMap<Integer, String> innerMap = entry.getValue();
    if (innerMap == null) {
        continue;
    }
    for (Entry<Integer, String> innerEntry : innerMap.entrySet())
        System.out.println("key:" + innerEntry.getKey() + " value: " + innerEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

java Collections provide facility of `EntrySet`. This is a list of objects which contain individual keys and values as its properties. You can take a iterator out of this list.

You can get keys as follows.

```
Iterator i= subitems.entrySet().iterator();

while(i.hasNext()){

String key= i.next().getkey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over entries using `entrySet().iterator()` on the first `HashMap` or get the keys and iterate over them:  Instead of `subitems.values().iterator()` use `subitems.keys().iterator()` and use the next key to get the inner hashmap.