# Is this an ugly/bad design for a data-structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

Is this data structure a bad design choice somehow? 
Basically every map is a user, which has a bunch of different kinds of fields. Every kind of field is a key in the map, and has a List of the fields(ControlTemplate) that are of that kind.

```
 protected ArrayList<Map<String, List<ControlTemplate>>> doInBackground(Void... params)
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you make a `User` class?

Comment: This is what a person with background in dynamic languages would write. It is not good Java style and if you pursue it, you'll be facing new problems each day.

Comment: In any case, you could drop `ArrayList` at the start in favour of `List`.

Comment: Yes, it's a bad design. It's basically another case of [object denial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3725728/40342).

Comment: After all those denials: it would make sense if you do *nothing* with the fields; no suddenly conversion/casting and retrieving values. A generic bean utility, code generator or so. Some extended collection classes (MultiSet or so) certainly would make sense, if not abstraction of an own class. That `doInBackground` is an odd description reminding me of my time sheets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be better if you create a `User` class. And if it is not absolutely necessary you should make an attribute for each property of the user instead of using a map.

Comment: A User class will be good, however the map is probably necessary to keep. The size and groups of fields will differ from user to user etc.

Comment: @Rickard Jimmy answer is correct. What is the problem of creating a `User` class in your project?

Comment: @Rickard Can you give some example fields?

Comment: @Rickard: nothing's wrong with the User class having a Map of attributes internally.

Comment: @JimmyT. This is an Android app, and the user fields will vary depending on who is using it. For some it might only be name, phone and mail, for others it might include address, family etc. These fields will be grouped differently as well.

Comment: @Rickard What do you mean when you say "grouped differently"? Address has other properties, family other properties...?

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX In some views only a couple of fields fit, so a group defines what fields those are. Group1 will always be displayed, in search results, profile view etc, while Group2 and Group3 might only be displayed in profile view. And each group is represented by a key and an ArrayList of ControlTemplates.

Comment: @Rickard Wow... I can't follow you, sorry... This is too strange :S I've never developed an application as strange as that one you are working on.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX Heh, that's ok, me neither. It's supposed to be the same isntallation for several different customers with different specs.

Answer (score 0):

One concept of good `OOD` is encapsulation. That means that you dont't have compley datastructures like your list but classes which whole purpose is to store data and make an abstraction.