# How can I return different array lists types on java?

Tags: java

I have one method in which I create and add items to 3 array lists, 2 of them `<String>` and the other one as `<Integer>`. The problem is that I need to use them (all 3) in another method which will remove the item(s) that I want to remove from them.

This is the "add" method:

```
public static void Hire () throws IOException{
    String name;
    String category,st_wage,st_id;
    int wage,id;

    BufferedReader ob_name = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader ob_category = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader ob_wage = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader ob_id = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    //name on name_list[id]
    //cat. on cat_list[id]
    //wage on wage_list[id]
    System.out.println("Driver Name: ");

    name = ob_name.readLine();

    System.out.println("Driver License: ");
    System.out.println("1 - Motorcycle");
    System.out.println("2 - Van");
    System.out.println("3 - Truck");

    category = ob_category.readLine();

    System.out.println("Wage: ");

    st_wage = ob_wage.readLine();
    wage = Integer.parseInt(st_wage);

    System.out.println("Driver ID: ");

    st_id = ob_id.readLine();
    id = Integer.parseInt(st_id);

    ArrayList<String> name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    name_list.add(id, name);

    ArrayList<String> cat_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    cat_list.add(id, category);

    ArrayList<Integer> wage_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    wage_list.add(id, wage);

    Manage();

}
```

And this is the "remove" method:

```
public static void Fire (ArrayList<String> name_list, ArrayList<String> cat_list, ArrayList<String> wage_list) throws IOException{
    int id;
    BufferedReader ob_id = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader ob_op = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    //name on name_list[id]
    //cat on cat_list[id]
    //wage on wage_list[id]
    System.out.println("Driver ID: ");

    String st_id = ob_id.readLine();
    id = Integer.parseInt(st_id);

    String name = name_list.get(id);

    System.out.println("Are You Sure to fire Driver "+name+"? (Y/N)");

    char op = (char) ob_op.read();

    if(op == 'Y' || op == 'y'){
        name_list.remove(id);

        cat_list.remove(id);

        wage_list.remove(id);
    }

    Manage();

}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to create a class for a driver instead. This is messy.

Comment: You have 5 extra BufferedReaders in your code, you only need one.

Comment: A classical case of [object denial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3725728/40342): You should not use parallel lists, but rather a single list of `Driver` objects. And on an unrelated note: it's unnecessary to create multiple `BufferedReader` and it can even be harmful, so use just a single one.

Comment: Just an opinion, your variable names are not of Java style. You should use camel casing.

Comment: What is `add(id, name)`? How would that work in a simple `List`?! And why do you need a list? The function creates the three new lists and adds a single item to each. And why do you need *three* lists? It looks like you want an object with an id, name, cat, and wage--and add *those* to a list. This means the list wouldn't be created in the `add` function, but instead that `add` would stick that object at the end of a new list. Good luck.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ok, but how do I put different "columns" on that list?

Comment: @user2567064: by creating a class `Driver` that has the properties `id`, `categories` and `wage` (usually that means those fields and the respective getters/setters).

Answer (score 0):

You will get Array Index out of bound exception when adding elements in list with own index. For your requirement all your need is a simple class

```
public class Driver {
  public String id ;
  public String name ;
  public String category ;
  public double wage ;

  public Driver(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name =name;
  }  

  // getter and setter methods
}
```

Create a new instance of Driver after getting all inputs from user and keep it in a `Map`

```
// Key = driverId and value = DriverEntity   
HashMap<String,Driver> map = new HashMap();
```

Further you can add or remove with driver Id.