# Can I create an ArrayList of different types in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to create an `ArrayList` and fill it with `BigDecimals` and a `Date` elements, how do I do?

Should I create a new Class with all the types I need in the ArrayList and then use it as the type?

Comment: you can, doesn't mean you should ;-)

Comment: It is possible, but from a design-perspective you should really not do that. There is a reason for the strong typing of Java and you can for sure solve your problem without trying to break it

Comment: @LionC : what you are saying is absolutely correct ,please mention the reason in short

Comment: You can, but Java is strongly typed language. This should make you think that you're idea it's not so brilliant.

Comment: @Hussain I thought opening that topic in the comments could go a bit too deep, as it often causes discussion

Comment: You should create a class which has a field for each piece of information you want to store.  An arraylist might be simple to create but working with A collection of data will be a nightmare compared with using a proper class.

Comment: @LionC : i totally agrre with it , but by any chance if you come across a link regarding please do mention to the needy guy :)

Comment: Answering to the 2nd question: I don't think it's the right way, you should use two different list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be interesting to know what you try to achieve.

If the `BigDecimal`s and `Date`s do **have a logical relation**, e.g. like a the amount of a bank transaction and it's placed date, than you should think about introducing a new class that brings both together (hopefully named BankTransaction). You can than put objects of this class in the `List`.

If the `BigDecimal`s and `Date`s have **nothing to do with each other** why do you want to store them in the same list? In this case you will confuse other developers since they must take a look at the code that interpretes the List and they can not guess what it means because of the list's type.

Nevertheless you can use the `List<Object>` approach, but this would not be self-explanantory code like `List<BankTransaction>` for example.

Comment: If I interpret OP:s question correctly, this answer should help the most.

Comment: Yes the date has a relation with the other components, and it's about a BankTransaction so I will create a new class. Thanks

Comment: Another case of [Object Denial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map) solved ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `List<Object>`

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Although this way works properly and fits your question, you should definitly check your requirements and if you really need to add `Date`s and `BigDecimal`s to the same `List`, as this is **not** a good practice.

Comment: But it's really dirty, consider making 2 Lists instead ;)

Comment: Java 7 is not brand-new now, I think we can safely use `new ArrayList<>()` in our example code now.

Comment: @Theolodis thats true, but without more information about the exact requirement it is hard to recommend something that would fit better.

Comment: @user1983983 this wasn't for you, but for the OP ;)
Maybe you add it to the answer, just to make sure noone uses it without considering any other (better) solution :P

Answer (score 1):

Use code like below:

```
List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
list2.add(new BigDecimal(3242));
list2.add(new Date());
for (Object object : list2) {
  if(object instanceof Date) {
    // your logic on date
  } else if (object instanceof BigDecimal) {
    // your logic on BigDecimal
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote. While this is technically correct, I can't condone such an approach without at least a comment on why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer,Agreed. But about down vote, the question got up votes, why an answer to such a question down vote?

Answer (score 0):

All classes in Java inherit from the base `Object` class, so you can just create an ArrayList that accepts `Object` instances, and put whatever you like in it:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new Date()); // adds a Date instance
list.add(new BigDecimal()); // adds a BigDecimal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>()
```

try this. Use an Object class of java