# how do I sort a 2D array of ints in java by a certain column

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a 2d array of integers which hold a date: the month is at index 0, the day at index 1, and the year at index 2

```
date [0][0] = 10;
date [0][1] = 14;
date [0][2] = 2013;
System.out.println(date[0][0] + "-" + date[0][1] + "-" + date[0][2]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
10-14-2013
```

If I had lots of these, would it be possible to sort these dates in chronological order?

This is what I have so far:

```
for(int i =0; i < date.length; i++)
{
    Arrays.sort(date[i]);
}
```

but this, instead, switches my day with the month.

After searching, I found that a few people on the stack were using the comparator class for sorting. Is it possible to use that?

Comment: day at index 1 month at index 0? not sure there are 14 months...

Comment: Using a comparator is the right way.

Comment: unrelated, but it would be better to use a class to represent one date instead of an array.

Comment: I was going to say as @Henry, OP do you know `OOP`? This could easily be done that way.

Comment: If you convert to String with the format year-mm-dd (or yyyymmdd), you can exploit the lexicographical String ordering but you should probably use a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: If I have the date in a string, could I use the predefined date object? would that be better than making my own date class as proposed below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would make more sense to use a date object (you're in [object denial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3725728/2095090)), it isn't hard to sort this 2D array using a custom comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b)  {
        // compare years
        if (a[2] == b[2]) {
            // compare months
            if (a[0] == b[0]) {
                return Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]);
            } else {
                // compare days
                return Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]);
            }
        } else {
            return Integer.compare(a[2], b[2]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use an array of [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects? It seems to implement what you are trying to do with this 2D array already.

Actually should use [Calendar.set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) which replaces the link above

Comment: If I have a string: "10-12-2013" could I make that a date object?

Comment: because I first have a string and then convert it to a 2d array in order to sort

Comment: Can convert string to int via Integer.parseInt("1234")

Answer (score 0):

Abstract date attributes day, month, year into a custom Date object.

```
public class Date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

}
```

Your Date class should implement comparator/comparable interface and then provide compare/comareTo method implementations.

Then you are ready to sort your array/list of Date objects using inbuilt Java's sort method.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Date Object. Just parse your string into month,day and year. 
Then implement the compareTo interface.

```
Public class Date implements compareTo{
private int day,month,year;

public Date(int d,int m,int y ){

day=d;
month=m;
year=y;

}
public int compareTo(Date date){
if(year<date.year)
return -1;
else if(year>date.year)
return 1; 
else if(year==date.year)
if(month<date.month)
return -1
else if (month>date.month)
return 1; 
else if(month==date.month)
if (day>date.day)
return 1;
else if (day<date.day)
return -1;
else return 0; //i.e the two dates are equal since they have the same day,month and year

}


}
```

Once you do that,implement your sort method according to the CompareTo method. 
EDIT- And once you do that, you need a normal array not a 2D one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the array structure, use some thing similar to ***counting/radix sort*** will save the day

First: for year, store all the **indexes** of items have the same years into **one list**.

For each year list, sort them by month in **similar way** as for year.

Do something similar for day.

Print all the index, starting from year to year. Enjoy :)

But Date type with in-built comparable method will be the best.

**Note**: actually, the key point is **working with index** and using some **stable sort** to sort them from 3 different perspective : year, month and day

Looking at your comment, you could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to **convert from string to date**.