# inbuilt Data Structure in C#, which can hold pair like Key, Value, Value

Tags: c#

I am looking for a inbuilt Data Structure in C#, which can hold pair like Key, Value, Value.

For Example for Dictionary in C# we have Key and Value. Similarly I am Looking a inbuilt data structure, which holds Key, Value, Value. It should be generic.

Comment: `Dictionary<T, MyCustomClass>` and expose two `Value` properties in `MyCustomClass`

Comment: Or if you really want only build in types `Dictionary<T1, Tuple<T2, T3>>`

Comment: Similar question for Java; the ansers can be applied to C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725703/how-to-store-more-than-one-string-in-a-map

Comment: Thanks Meehow for your input:-)

Answer (score 3):

How about `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`?

It even supports up to 8 values.

Comment: but this doesn't force the value for T1 to be unique

Comment: He gave the dictionary as example. And such a data structure could never force the value to be unique. That has to be done by the containing data structure

Comment: he did ask for "Key, Value, Value" though; as opposed to "Value, Value, Value"

Comment: A key is nothing more than a value, just with a different meaning. If you define T1 to be a key in your application, then it is a key.

Comment: He was also asking for one data structure that can handle this case, and tuple is the only one that can without nesting classes

Comment: that's fair - we'll see if the OP clarifies then :)

Comment: Thanks Domysee for your input :-).

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<T1, Tuple<T2, T3>>` works, as @Mant101 said in the comments.
or `Dictionary<T1, KeyValuePair<T2, T3>>` if there is also a key-value relationship between T2 and T3

Comment: KeyValuePair is not good unless there really is a key/value relationship between T2 and T3.